# Which apps are available to create start up explain videos?

Tags: flash, animation, video, adobe

I was wondering if there is any easy tool to use in order to create a start up video?
I know there is the Adobe After Effect option, which is extremely expansive.

Do you guys know any tool that allows you to create an animation, easily? for a startup site, a video that explains what the startup do?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for animation software, you could look at [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) for 3D or [Synfig](http://www.synfig.org/) for 2D. They're both Open-Source and Free.